# Fair price to play a dice game

Tags: probability, game-theory

We play a game with a pot and a single die. The pot starts off empty.

- if the die roll is  1, 2 or 3, I put 1 pound in the pot, and the die is thrown again
- if its 4 or 5, the game finishes, and you win whatever is in the pot
- if its 6, you leave with nothing

**What is the fair price for you to play this game?**

1. 1/2
2. 1/3
3. 3/2
4. 2/3

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: The interesting thing about this game is that $n$ (i.e. the number of throws) is variable (this game can end in 2 throws or in 20 throws) whereas the probabilities are fixed in each throw. Markov comes to mind

Comment: Let $X\sim \text{Geometric}(1/2)$ represent the number of times you roll the dice, $P$ represent your profit, and $p$ the price to play the game. Note $P|X$ is supported on $\{-p,X-p-1\}$. Find this conditional distribution, then use total law of expectation to establish $p$ that makes $\mathbb{E}(P)=0$.

Comment: What's the probability of winning exactly $1$?  Exactly $2$?  Exactly $73$? Exactly $n$? Now just sum.  There are other approaches, but this one is pretty easy.

Answer (score 1):

This question is equivalent to asking the expected value of the price in the pot when the game ends.

There’s a $\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{3}$ chance the total is 1 (1, 2, or 3 and then 4 or 5), $\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{3}$ chance the total is 2 (1, 2, or 3 and then 1, 2, or 3 and then 4 or 5), and so on, such that we want to find $\frac{1}{3}(1\cdot (\frac{1}{2})^1+2\cdot (\frac{1}{2})^2+3\cdot (\frac{1}{2})^3+\dots).$

Let $S = \frac{1}{3}(1\cdot (\frac{1}{2})^1+2\cdot (\frac{1}{2})^2+3\cdot (\frac{1}{2})^3+\dots)$

Then $\frac{S}{2} = \frac{1}{3} (1\cdot (\frac{1}{2})^2+2\cdot (\frac{1}{2})^3 + \dots)$

Subtracting the two equations gets $S-\frac{S}{2} = \frac{1}{3}(1\cdot (\frac{1}{2})^1 + 1\cdot (\frac{1}{2})^2+1\cdot (\frac{1}{2})^3+\dots).$ The parentheses is just equal to $1,$ so $\frac{S}{2} = \frac{1}{3}\cdot 1,$ so $S = \boxed{\frac{2}{3}.}$